# Ubuntu does not recognize ED elements disk 1 TB?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have an external disk called WD elments 1 TB when I run ubuntu and try to find my external disk ubuntu does not regonize but when I run the command : dmesg  , using my terminal I can found it like you can see here:

[image: screenshot]

when I try to access it I am not able to find it in my ubuntu OS , any idea?

Comment: You mention Ubuntu, but were not specific as to which Ubuntu product & release you're asking about (Server? Desktop? what release of that *unstated* product). Did you try and `mount` it? or have you used a partitioning tool & tried to partition it (*given you mention partitioning*) as you appear to have pasted `dmesg` or system logs without any context of what you tried.

Comment: What does the GNOME Disk utility ("Disks" from the Gnome search menu) show?

Comment: And what does `lsblk -f` tell you?